# Sub-string without counting blank spaces

Tags: php

I want to make a sub-string, where the `$count` only counts letters, not spaces.  This is what I have so far:

```
$string ="vikas tyagi php";
$string = substr($string, 0, 10);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
vikas tyag
```

Desired output (I don't want to count the spaces):

```
vikas tyagi
```

How would I do this?

i want extract string with those condition

1)Base on count letter

2)Without white space

3)String limit also

Comment: black space? you mean white space or more popularly called spaces?

Comment: yes @Prisoner black space = white space

Comment: @vikastyagi hey concerning your other question that you deleted for some reason, I got you answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ekHr2/8/ not sure why you deleted the question :)

Comment: join me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21054/for-me-and-vikas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply count the spaces and add them to the desired length of the capture:

```
function spaceless_substr($string, $start, $count) {
    return substr($string, $start, ($count+substr_count($string, ' ', $start, $count)));
}

$string ="vikas tyagi asd sd as asd";
echo substr($string, 0, 14);
// return: "vikas tyagi a"
echo spaceless_substr($string, 0, 14);
// return: "vikas tyagi asd"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can do it like so:

```
<?php
    $string = "vikas tyagi";
    $lettercount = strlen(str_replace(' ', '', $string));
    echo $string . ' contains ' . $lettercount . ' letters';
?>
```

Here I've used [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen) on a version of `$string` with spaces removed using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

**Addition**

I didn't understand the question

**Addition**

Here's my first crack at this, feel free to amend where you see fit:

```
$string = "vikas tyagi";

function my_substr($string, $start, $length)
{
    $substr = substr($string, $start, $length);
    $spaces = count(explode(' ', $substr)) - 1;
    if ($spaces > 0)
    {
        return substr($string, $start, $length + $spaces);
    }
    return $substr;
}

echo my_substr($string, 0, 10);
```

Comment: he wants the actual string to be modified (but not with white space). So he wants the string to be "vikas tyag" when he does: `substr("vikas tyagi", 0, 10);`

Comment: i want extract string with those condition 1)base on count letter 2)without white space 3)string limit also

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode(" ",$str);
$length = 10;
for ($i = 0, $currIndex = 0, $finalstring = ""; $currIndex < $length; $i++){
    $finalstring .= " ".substr($arr[$i], 0, $length - $currIndex);
    $currIndex += strlen($arr[$i]);
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://codepad.org/lv4KEsAi