# Why does this happen with substr space

Tags: php

i wondering why substr function count space 
Example:

```
$text= 'Hello World';
echo substr($text,0,6);
```

the output will be

> Hello

but i want to be

> Hello w

Thanks for any help

Comment: substr counts space because space is a position in the string.  But there is an answer to what you want here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840389/sub-string-without-counting-blank-spaces

Answer (score 0):

The `substr()` function counts from the first character as `0` and this includes the space as well.

This should give your desired output:

```
$text= 'Hello World';
echo substr($text,0,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

A space character is counted just like any other character.  To get the output you want you need to use:

```
$text= 'Hello World';
echo substr($text,0,7);
```