# How to display a string with a character limit and charter limit is exclude space on that string in php

Tags: javascript, php, string, replace

I want to display a  string   as  specific number of count  but  count exclude  space on that string.For example   if  a string is "I want to go Edinburgh"  then it contain 4 spaces and it total length is 22 characters including spaces.I want to display this string as 15 character limit   so i use following  php code

```
$para ="I want to go Edinburgh";
echo  substr($para,0,15);
```

its output is

> ->I want to go Ed

here 4 space is counted as 15 character limit

Actually my expected  result is:

> I want to go Edinbu (4 space is not  counted)

So i want to display above result in php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sub-string without counting blank spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840389/sub-string-without-counting-blank-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

First count total no of space and add it to `substr()`

```
$i =15;
$para ="I want to go Edinburgh";
$string = substr($para,0,$i); 
$total_space =  substr_count($string, ' ');

echo substr($para,0,$i+$total_space);
```

**output**

```
I want to go Edinbu
```

Comment: Perfect  answer and logic

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
function spaceless_substr($string, $start, $count) {
    return substr($string, $start, ($count+substr_count($string, ' ', $start, $count)));
}

$string ="I want to go Edinburgh";

echo spaceless_substr($string, 0, 15);
```